# login strategy using augularfire OAuth to facebook

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am using code below on loginCtrl controller and login.html. It works. but I am having trouble setting workflow working properly. I would like to do something like this.

```
//check if the current $scope has authData
 //if so redirect to (or render) home.html
//if not stay in the login page.
```

I have new to angular and trying to figure out. on nodejs with express, it seemed to be clear to me that I jsut render or redirect when the received data is good. confusing how to handle in angular.

javascript

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, Login) {


  $scope.login = function() {
    Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
        .then(function(authData){
          console.log(authData);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          if(err) {
           console.log("Authentication failed!!", err);
          }
        })
  };
})

.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
  var usersRef = new Firebase("https://dazzling-heat-4971.firebaseio.com/users");
  return $firebaseAuth(usersRef);
})
```

html

```
<ion-content class="padding loginbox">
  <div ng-hide="!authData" ng-click="login('facebook')">  
    <!-- <a ui-sref="home" ng-if="verifyLogin()"> -->
      <button class="button button-positive icon ion-social-facebook">
        Login with Facebook
      </button>
    <!-- </a> -->
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularFire has built-in support for simplifying routing and authentication.

Rather than checking for an authenticated user in your controller, **you can inject the currently authenticated user.**

This means you don't have to do any `if else` checks in your controller or view, which will simplify the code.

You can inject the user through the `resolve()` function in the router.Ionic uses `ui-router`. After you log the user in you'll ned to call `$state.$go()` with the route name. This will *route* to the view and invoke the controller.

The style of code below comes from the Angular Style Guide. It's just another way of writing Angular code, so don't let it distract you too much.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
   .run(ApplicationRunSettings)
   .config(ApplicationConfig)
   .controller('loginCtrl', LoginCtrl);

// The authData param is injected from the router
function UserProfileCtrl($scope, authData) {
  $scope.user = authData;
}

function LoginCtrl($scope, Auth) {
   Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
    .then(function(authData){
      $state.go('userProfile');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      if(err) {
       console.log("Authentication failed!!", err);
      }
    })
}

// Set up the router to resolve authenticated users
function ApplicationConfig($stateConfig) {
   $stateProvider
     .state("home", {
       controller: "UserProfileCtrl",
       templateUrl: "views/userProfile.html",
       resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
           return Auth.$waitForAuth();
        }]
      }
   }
}

// When there's an error, go to the home view
function ApplicationRunSettings($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event) {
  // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
  // and redirect the user back to the home page
  if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    $state.go("home");
  }
}
```

Check out [the AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers) on authenticating with routers for more info.